# Gray box with three dots on a tab in MS Word - how can I remove it? It looks like some sort of text box

Tags: microsoft-word

What is this gray box and how can I remove it from my Word document?

[image]

Comment: I think it is related some comment section but I have deleted all comments from the doc but still see those boxes.

Comment: In recent versions of Word, if you click on the object, a tab for the tools associated with the object will be added to the ribbon.

Comment: That looks like a Content Control. Right-click on it and select properties. Uncheck any box preventing deletion in the properties and then delete it.

Comment: Thanks - yes right click --> remove content control solved the issue.